# indexing of array from form

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

recently I got a problem when posting data from form - I send data like this:

```
SamplesAmount[2]: 1
SamplesAsArray[2]: foo
SamplesAmount[1]: 4
SamplesAsArray[1]: bar
```

Then in model I get both variables without any data. Is it possible to get those data even when they are not indexed from 0 and they will not contain all indexes (due to deleting of elements etc)?

Many thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
definition of variables in Model:

```
public string[][] SamplesAsArray {get;set;}
public int[] SamplesAmount {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used this solution:

```
public Dictionary<int, string[]> SamplesAsArray {get; set;}
public Dictionary<int, int> SamplesAmount {get; set;}
```

and now I'm able to get items with any number.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden input in your form:(use `Item.Index`)

```
<input type="hidden" name="SamplesAmount.Index" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="SamplesAmount[1]" value="4" />

<input type="hidden" name="SamplesAmount.Index" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="SamplesAmount[2]" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="SamplesAsArray.Index" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="SamplesAsArray[1]" value="bar" />

<input type="hidden" name="SamplesAsArray.Index" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="SamplesAsArray[2]" value="foo" />
```

Test result:

[image]